# jquery .get problem

Tags: php, jquery, get

i have this html ul code

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='1' > 111111 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='2' > 222222 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='3' > 333333 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='4' > 444444 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='5' > 555555 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='6' > 666666 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='7' > 777777 </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to make this

when user click on any hyper link i make alt for it contain id number

J Query should take this id and send get request to File and load html code

The Problem Is How to add the answer code from file after the li he click on it

mean  if i clicked the first link

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='1' > 111111 </a> </li>
  **My Loaded code should apper here**
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='2' > 222222 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='3' > 333333 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='4' > 444444 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='5' > 555555 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='6' > 666666 </a> </li>
  <li> <a href='#' class='approch' alt='7' > 777777 </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you , Tim Büthe for edit my question :) it look like good now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
$("a").load(url, function(data) {
    $(this).parent().after(data);
});
```

if you are using the a-elements href as url source you can do it like: http://jsbin.com/uvipaj/edit

Comment: i added this code , he work but all li a take attr from file and all after it also contain the value from file

Comment: Look at @Drake code below that will do what you are looking for.

Comment: There Is Only One Problem :(  Also The Link I clicked have the value from the file

Comment: replace `url` with `this.href` ? but @Drake did a much better answer with this, dont understand why you marked me as the solution. I used the `url` name bacause you didnt say where that url would come from. Dont know why the down vote either to be honest. added a live example with the code above.

Comment: @Drake is very good man and he tried to help me and i saw this , and i select you answer because i tried all answeres your answer was very close ,  your answer to change the link value ???

Comment: Look at the jsbin link, I take the url from the actually a-element and append whatever response that url gives me, you may have to look at the data you get from the url to filter out the data you want to insert after your `li`.

Comment: ok it work fine now :) thank you and thanks to all people who tried to help me

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".approach").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get("http://yourwebsite.com/yourfile.php?id=" + $(this).attr("alt"), function(data){
        $(this).parent().insertAfter(unescape(data));
    });
});
```

sounds about right

Comment: i added this code but nothing happen             $(".approach").click(function(){

            $.get("h_app.php?id=" + $(this).attr("alt"), function(data){
               $(this).html(unescape(data));
            });

            return false;
        });

Comment: I dont think there is a reason for returning false, Also you are setting the anchor's html. Not after it. Lastly, check with any debugger such as firebug if that file is in the same directory as your javascript file and that the callback is being called.

Comment: return false will help you if you dont want your hash sign when you click on the a-element.

Comment: I see, I usually just add an e var to the parameters of the for event. Then set it to prevent the default event. Updated with that, also good to know about that false method :]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.approch').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('alt');
    var newli = '<li></li>';
    $(this).closest('li').after(newli);
    newli.load('/file.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().append('<br>'+$(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/XmARg/1/)

You would need to tweak it to fit your needs, but I think the best method should be to create a div bellow every li and fill it with the text you want

Comment: your code is work fine but it add the value of attr alt of the link how can i make it append value from file

Comment: SamarLover I only developed a small example, not the complete code. Since you didn't provide us with all your code, it was up to you to replace the example with your own code